# Move a selectedNode Up and Down in Treelist By clicking Buttons

Tags: c#

How to move selectedNode up and down when click the Up and down button. selectedNode always visible in treelist control. so that Treelist can scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, It might be helpful

```
 if(mainTreelist.FocusedNode.Expanded)
            {
                mainTreelist.MoveNode(mainTreelist.FocusedNode, mainTreelist.FocusedNode.NextVisibleNode, true);
                mainTreelist.MakeNodeVisible(mainTreelist.FocusedNode);
            }
```

Which moves the selected node to next node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But If the node is not expanded in this case I need to selected node moves to next position. but in this code selected node added to the childnode for the NextNode.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Method :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
  node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
  treeView1.SelectedNode = node.NextVisibleNode;
  node.TreeView.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for repIied me.But I need to move the selectedNode to next & previous position in the treelist and if the selected node as a child node that childnode move to another parent node as well. simply moves the selectedNode up and down in the list.